# Microchip C18 send data to Terminal as numeric

Tags: microchip, usart, mplab-c18

I am working on a project on which i need to send data over USART to terminal.
I need to display the data as the numeric value (0-255) of the char (which collected from the EEPROM

i have managed to send the char as is to the terminal (using Putty or TerMite)
My problem starts where the value of the char is non-printable

That's why i will need to convert the value of the char to numeric

Example: when the data acquired from the EEPROM is 0x31 my routine will send '1' but i will need to send '049' or '49' to the terminal

```
void SendToSer(void) {

unsigned char Looper;

for (Looper=EEPROM_START;Looper<EEPROM_END;Looper++){
    ReadEEPROM(Looper);    //returns ReadResult
    Write1USART((char) ReadResult); //Sends the ASCII
    ClrWdt();   
}
```

}

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `sprintf`?

Comment: No, can you suggest a syntax?, includes?

Comment: All in the [C18 Libraries](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB_C18_Libraries_51297f.pdf) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The sprintf as jolati suggested can be a good work horse in some situations or, even better, snprintf if it is available for your version of C18. Both routines follow the standard printf formatting (ex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main() {
    char buffer[80];
    unsigned char len, number = 152;

    // Write at most 80 bytes to our buffer
    len = snprintf(buffer, 80, "sprintf string, heres a number: %d", number);
    // buffer now contains our string, len is the number of bytes written

    // or
    len = printf(buffer, "... %d",number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks , I've decided to take it the long way......

Here's what i've done is:

Manipulated the int value of the char to 3 new char
(i.e.) 243 became 3 chars -   50,52,51 (the ASCII of the digits)

(maybe its long and lame but it works like a charm)

heres the script....

```
void ConvertToNumeric(unsigned char IsValue, unsigned int LineNumber){
unsigned int SourceInt;

ClrWdt();
if (IsValue == 1){
    SourceInt = (int) ReadResult;
}else{
    SourceInt = (int) LineNumber;
    LineNumber++;
}

ClrWdt();
switch (SourceInt/100){         
    case 2 :    FirstChar = 50; SourceInt = SourceInt - 200;    break;
    case 1 :    FirstChar = 49; SourceInt = SourceInt - 100;    break;
    case 0:     FirstChar = 48;             break;
}

switch (SourceInt/10){
    case 9 :SecondChar = 57;    SourceInt = SourceInt - 90;         break;
    case 8 :SecondChar = 56;    SourceInt = SourceInt - 80;         break;
    case 7 :SecondChar = 55;    SourceInt = SourceInt - 70;         break;
    case 6 :SecondChar = 54;    SourceInt = SourceInt - 60;         break;
    case 5 :SecondChar = 53;    SourceInt = SourceInt - 50;         break;
    case 4 :SecondChar = 52;    SourceInt = SourceInt - 40;         break;
    case 3 :SecondChar = 51;    SourceInt = SourceInt - 30;         break;
    case 2 :SecondChar = 50;    SourceInt = SourceInt - 20;         break;
    case 1 :SecondChar = 49;    SourceInt = SourceInt - 10;         break;
    case 0 :SecondChar = 48;                                                break;
}

switch (SourceInt){
    case 9:         ThirdChar= 57;          break;
    case 8:         ThirdChar= 56;          break;
    case 7:         ThirdChar= 55;          break;
    case 6:         ThirdChar= 54;          break;
    case 5:         ThirdChar= 53;          break;
    case 4:         ThirdChar= 52;          break;
    case 3:         ThirdChar= 51;          break;
    case 2:         ThirdChar= 50;          break;
    case 1:         ThirdChar= 49;          break;
    case 0:         ThirdChar= 48;          break;  
}

ResultInChars[0] = FirstChar;
ResultInChars[1] = SecondChar;
ResultInChars[2] = ThirdChar;
ResultInChars[3] = '   ';
ResultInChars[4] = NULL;
ResultInChars[5] = NULL;
ResultInChars[6] = NULL;
```

}

later i have used puts1USART with an array containing 3 above chars (FirstChar, SecondChar & ThirdChar)

i've also added a "lineNumber" before every 4 values and CrLf after the forth value 
and it has resulted an output looks like that.....

[output to terminal in Putty over Serial port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVege.png)

and its working......

thanks for your help

I would apriciate your suggestions,
Guy